# Cakephp Validation tweak

Tags: validation, cakephp, server-side

I have added multiple validation rule for one field

```
Array
(
    [email] => Array
    (
        [rule] => email
        [message] => Please input a valid email address
    )
    [notEmpty] => Array
    (
        [rule] => notEmpty
        [message] => This field is required
    )

)
```

I want if filed empty then error should be "This field is required" and if its invalid mail address then "Please input a valid email address".

I am getting email address error in both case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try switching the order of the two rules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch the order of the validation rules so that it checks `notEmpty` first. What is happening is that if the field is blank it is invalidating the field as not being a valid email (because it is not) and not hitting the second rule.

You could also try adding `'allowEmpty' => true` to the `email` rule as this would skip the validation rule if the field is empty, but it is best to make sure you order the rules according to the order you want/need them evaluating in (it makes the code more readable).

```
Array
(
    [notEmpty] => Array
    (
        [rule] => notEmpty
        [message] => This field is required
    )
    [email] => Array
    (
        [rule] => email
        [message] => Please input a valid email address
        [allowEmpty] => true
    )

)
```